# Увеличить длину/ширину отдельного грида

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Можно ли изменить длину отдельного блока? Например блок с текстом добавить плюс 50 пикселей снизу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно ли изменить длину отдельного блока,можно.Где код?Зачем два одинаковых img?

Comment: Можно, добавьте ВАШ [mcve]

Comment: Можно, увеличивай.

Comment: Модератор разрешил,теперь точно можно)))